# Waveform Audio buffer

Tags: vb.net

i look at this article in msdn Recording and Playing Sound with the Waveform Audio Interface  and download the P/Invoke Library Sample that record using wave in and wave out .
how do i get the data from  buffer (Waveform Audio Interface) (wave in) while recording and play it using c# or vb (wave out) ,
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library, it takes care of this for you.